# Create new enum inheriting props from other enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I was googling this before asking and I've found a lot of questions but all of them were asking how to convert/join two enums into a type but in my case I want to create another enum inheriting values (like class extends) from a existent enum.

Example, I have the following enum:

```
enum Enum1 {
  a = 'a'
}
```

And I want to create another enum inheriting `Enum1` props. What I've tryed:

```
enum Enum2 {
  // this gives me the error: Enum member expected
  ...Enum1,
  b = 'b'
}

// also don't work 
enum Enum2 extends Enum1 {
  b = 'b'
}
```

I want to be able to access `Enum2.a` inheriting it's value from `Enum1`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not possible; enums in TypeScript are weirdly implemented anyways. It's almost always better to just use a static object constant.

Comment: There's no way to do this.  [microsoft/TypeScript#17592](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17592) is the relevant feature request but they won't think of implementing it until and unless enums in JavaScript are resolved.  The other questions you found are essentially asking the same thing as you; merging two enums is the same as taking one enum and merging extra enum pieces into it (if you imagine breaking the extra pieces into their own enum), and neither is directly supported.